# Deltalake on spark: Failure to initialize configuration while reading a table from azure storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-storage, delta-lake

### Context

I am trying to read a delta table stored on azure from a **local spark cluster**. The way I try to reach it is through **Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2** (`abfss://`), not the legacy Blob Storage

### Spark shell exploration

The final goal is a pyspark application but, to understand what's going on, I am trying to read the table from a spark shell. Here is how I launch it:

```bash
spark-shell \
--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.1  \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" \
--conf "fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net=<storage_key>"  \
```

Here is how I try to read the table

```scala
val dt = spark.read.format("delta").load(f"abfss://hub@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/fec/fec.delta")
```

and here is the error I get

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.KeyProviderException: Failure to initialize configuration
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:51)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getStorageAccountKey(AbfsConfiguration.java:548)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.initializeClient(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:1449)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:215)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:128)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaTableUtils$.findDeltaTableRoot(DeltaTable.scala:184)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource$.parsePathIdentifier(DeltaDataSource.scala:314)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.x$1$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.x$1(DeltaTableV2.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.timeTravelByPath$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.timeTravelByPath(DeltaTableV2.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.$anonfun$timeTravelSpec$1(DeltaTableV2.scala:99)
```

I have the impression that I followed the documentation and I was able to read delta table in python using [delta-rs](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs) with the very same creds: I am sure about the creds.

I probably forgot to set something but, the more I read docs, the more confused I feel. I also tried to set an [Oauth2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/azure-storage#azureserviceprincipal) auth but end up with the same exception. The more I think of it, the more I feel that `--conf "fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net=<storage_key>"` is not taken into account (but I have no idea why)

### Environment

- java 8.0.275.hs-adpt
- scala 2.13.10
- spark 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, authentication has to be set from the spark session

```bash
spark-shell \
--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.2  \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" \
```

and then

```scala
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net","<storage_key>")
val dt = spark.read.format("delta").load(f"abfss://hub@satestoct.dfs.core.windows.net/fec/fec.delta")
```